# Loging in with GUI on fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.3 keeps returning to login prompt and won't display desktop

Tags: 14.04, login

I tried logging in with my user account and as guest but neither works. I can login at the command line though. I tried doing fresh installs three times and even tried completely wiping the disk before installing once. I tried starting in safe mode and repairing packages but that hasn't helped. Laptop is an HP Compaq 6735s with an AMD Semptron SI-42 (no fancy graphics card or anything).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (although I couldn't log into the terminal). In the end, I held down Left-Shift at boot time to get the grub menu and chose an older kernel. Did you allow the installer to download updates?